# unable to render more than one partial with jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render, jbuilder

I have created a controllers function to get all elements of three different models. 
As simple as this:

```
def get_all_data
  @events = Event.all
  @activities = Activity.all
  @places = Place.all
end
```

Then in get_all_data.json:

```
json.partial! 'event', collection: @events
json.partial! 'activity', collection: @activities
json.partial! 'place', collection: @places
```

The problem is it only renders one partial, the last one. Am i missing something? Could this be done in some better way?

Comment: what are the partial files' name you've given? And by any chance, did you crate place partial first and then copied pasted for others the same partial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting them each in their own members of the JSON structure:

```
json.event do
  json.partial! 'event', collection: @events
end
json.activity do
  json.partial! 'activity', collection: @activities
end
json.place do
  json.partial! 'place', collection: @places
end
```

I feel like that should work.